# Regular Expression at the end of the string not matching

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract values in groups from a string. My regex is

```
string str = @"DEMOV 1'07"" MOT Lifestyle 503080 Pure Rain Nozzle Feb 13 472000";

const string type = @"(?<type>\w+)";
const string minutes = @"((?<minutes>\d+)\')?";
const string seconds = @"((?<seconds>\d+)\"")?";
const string body = @"(?<body>.+)";
const string id = @"(?<id>\s\d{6})?";

var pattern1 = String.Format(@"^{0}(?:\s\w+)?\s({1}{2}|{1}|{2})\s?{3}{4}$", type, minutes, seconds, body, id);
var m1 = Regex.Match(str, pattern1);
```

I am getting the match, but the the group is not getting the last 5 digit.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Please find below the output i am getting.

[image]

Comment: As `.+` is greedy it already matches those digits, thus the optional group doesn't match. You could use `.+?` for lazy matching.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the non-greedy version (use `.+?` for `body`), and don't add the spaces to the `id` group:

```
const string body = @"(?<body>.+?)";
const string id = @"\s(?<id>\d{6})?";
```

In action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L1yL3C

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. How do i get the values of the groups ie. how do i get the group value of id?

Comment: I figured it out. var min = m1.Groups["minutes"].Value;